# Sort List of POJO class dynamically

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

Consider I am having two different POJO class as below.

```
class Employee {
    String empId;
    
    Date empJoiningDate;
    BigDecimal empExperience;
}

class EmployeeDetails {
    String empName;
    String address;
    BigDecimal contactNo;
    Date empdob;
}
```

Required to create common method through which I can sort Employee or EmployeeDetails

```
sortbyProperty(List<T> list, String columnName, boolean ascOrder)
```

Tried with below code but not able to perform dynamically.

```
empList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getEmpId())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: If you are working in a Spring-Boot environment, think about whether you can utilize [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/paging-and-sorting.html) instead. It sounds like you are tasked to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What attributes are common amongst the two classes? Otherwise, you can make use of an argument of type `Function<T, U>` which doesn't save much looking at your current use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is cumbersome to implement and use:

- The result `Comparator` will be raw, unless we define `Class<R>` parameter, where `<R extends Comparable<R>>` (end of the answer).
- Extra `Class<T>` parameter is needed in any case.
- Reflection is needed (goodbye performance).
- The failures only appear at runtime.

The sorting itself using Stream API and a Comparator is simple. Consider this method:

```java
private <T> List<T> sortByProperty(List<T> list, Class<T> type, String columnName, boolean ascOrder) {
    return list.stream()
        .sorted(dynamicComparator(type, columnName, ascOrder))
        .toList();
}
```

All we are left with is to implement the Comparator. It looks like this:

```java
private <T> Comparator dynamicComparator(Class<T> type, String fieldName, boolean ascOrder) {
    final var method = Arrays.stream(type.getMethods())
        // find getWhatever or isWhatever method
        .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("get" + capitalize(fieldName))
            || m.getName().equals("is" + capitalize(fieldName)))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No getter for " + fieldName));

    return (o1, o2) -> {
        try {
            final var left = method.invoke(o1);
            final var right = method.invoke(o2);
            if (left instanceof Comparable comparableLeft && right instanceof Comparable comparableRight) {
                return ascOrder 
                    ? comparableLeft.compareTo(comparableRight)
                    : comparableRight.compareTo(comparableLeft);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(fieldName + " is not comparable");
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Also, this is needed:

```java
private String capitalize(String string) {
    return string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
}
```

---

The Comparator with an additional `Class<R>` parameter would look roughly like this (untested):

```java
private <T, R extends Comparable<R>> Comparator<T> dynamicComparator(Class<T> type, String fieldName, Class<R> columnType, boolean ascOrder) {
    // skipped...
    return (o1, o2) -> {
        try {
            final R left = (R) method.invoke(o1);
            final R right = (R) method.invoke(o2);
            return ascOrder ? left.compareTo(right) : right.compareTo(left);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fieldName + " is not comparable");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```